# Lounge access at Istanbul flying Indigo as M&S Elite

Tags: istanbul, turkish-airlines, lounges

I am a Turkish airlines Miles and Smiles Elite member. Next week I have a trip from Berlin to Istanbul flying Turkish and then an Indigo airlines flight to India from Istanbul

Would I still be able to use the Miles and Smiles lounge at Istanbul? Irrespective of whether Indigo is a Turkish partner airline my first leg (Berlin to Istanbul) is definitely on Turkish airlines. Would that count for lounge access?

Anyone know?

Edit: Indigo is NOT on Star Alliance. However Indigo seems to be a Turkish partner of some sort? See here:

https://www.turkishairlines.com/de-int/miles-and-smiles/program-partners/airlines/Indigo/

Comment: Turkish Airlines has a codeshare agreement with IndiGo for flights to/from India. If you have booked entire journey on single ticket, or, IST-India leg as separate ticket, with Turkish, then there should not be a problem. If IST-India leg is on IndiGo ticket, I don't think lounge access would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

As Indigo is not a Turkish Airlines/Star Alliance partner, I think the answer is no. The reason is that you're on two different tickets, so from the perspective of Turkish, you're flying on Indigo, which has no relation to Turkish Airways (i.e, you're the same as a random passenger). The fact that you have Turkish Airways status has no impact, since you normally need to be travelling on Turkish Airways (or with one of its partners) for it to have any effect.

Comment: Thanks! I've added some clarifications to the question. Would that change anything?

Comment: "These privileges only apply to Turkish Airlines marketed and IndiGo operated flights."

Are you on a single ticket or two separate tickets?

Comment: Whilst I *think* this answer is correct, it's not as simple as you've implied.  You've said "you're flying on Indigo, which has no relation to Turkish Airways", which is incorrect.  Indigo is wet leasing TK aircraft for the IST to India routes. That means the OP will be on a TK plane, with a TK crew and TK pilots. But it's an Indigo flight.  So I think you're right in saying no access...